# Use Twig Custom Set Variables From an Include

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to include a twig file with a bunch of custom set variables and then use the variables in the multiple other template files. Similar to how including a PHP file works.

I don't seem to have access to the variables set inside the include in my index file.

Is there any way to do this?

**Sample Code** **Edited*

Included File:

```
{# variables.html #}
{% set width = "100" %}
{% set height = "250" %}
```

Template File:

```
{# index.html #} 
{% include 'variables.html' %}
{{ width }}
{{ height }}
```

Expected Outcome:

```
100 250
```

Actual Outcome:

```
// Nothing gets output
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was just trying to do the same thing you were and came up with the following:

Created `snippets.twig` to maintain all these mini variables. In your case, you might call it `variables.twig`. In this file, I used a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) without any arguments. I was creating formatted entry date markup that I can use across all my templates and it looked like this:

```
{% macro entry_date() %}
<time datetime="{{post.post_date|date('m-d-Y')}}">{{post.post_date|date('F j, Y')}}</time>
{% endmacro %}
```

*note that the parenthesis after the name declaration were imperative*

In my main layout file, `layout.twig`, I referenced this macro via an [import](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/import.html) statement so it would be accessible in all child templates:

```
{% import "snippets.twig" as snippets %}
<!doctype html>
...
```

In my template files, I now have `snippets` accessible and can query it like any other variable:

```
{{ snippets.entry_date }}
```

**UPDATE**

This doesn't seem to correctly run code. If you're just storing static content, you should be good. You can also pass args to the macro so I imagine you could make some magic happen there but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Is this still the best answer?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know it is only possible with `{% extends %}` tag. Instead of including template with variables you should extend it.

Example:

**variables.tpl:**

```
{% set some_variable='123' %}
... more variables ...

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

**template.tpl**

```
{% extends 'variables.tpl' %}

{% block content %}
{{ some_variable }}
... more code which uses variables assigned in variables.tpl ...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Exactly what I am searching, but I am getting `template template.tpl cannot be used as trait` with this setup.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a template extension : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

```
post|entry_date
```